# I am creating next button on keyboard view it is not displaying on iphone 13 and above

Tags: ios, keyboard

[iPhone 12 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfDWY.png)

[iphone 13 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw6hi.png)

I am not getting next button on iphone 13 and above below iphone 13 is is coming.. am using above code for creating next button..
and adding this method in textfield delegate method.

```
-(void)addingNextButtonInKeyBoardInInputGroup{

    CGFloat return_key_width = ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 32)/3;
    UIButton *btnNext = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnNext.hidden = false;
    btnNext.frame = CGRectMake(8, 163, return_key_width, 48.5);
    btnNext.tag = 10001;
    btnNext.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false;
    [btnNext setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_next"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnNext addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIView *keyboardView = [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject] subviews] firstObject];
        CGFloat bottomPadding = 0;
        if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
            UIWindow *window = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow;
            bottomPadding = (window.safeAreaInsets.bottom * 2) + 5;
            if (bottomPadding > 5) {
                bottomPadding = bottomPadding + 5;
            }
        }
        [btnNext setFrame:CGRectMake(8, keyboardView.bounds.size.height - bottomPadding, return_key_width, 48.5)];

        [btnNext layoutIfNeeded];
        [keyboardView addSubview:btnNext];
    });
}
```

can you please help me what i did wrong..